# Swift 3: thumbnail from video

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, thumbnails

I need to create a thumbnail from videos stored locally on the device in Swift 3. I have following code:

```
func fetchFirstFrameOf(videoPath urlString: String) -> UIImage? {
    let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString).absoluteURL

    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: filePath, options: nil)
    let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = false

    do {
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

        return thumbnail

    } catch let error {
        print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now this works when I shoot a video and save it. But when I restart the app at a later point, no thumbnails are shown and following error is thrown:

> *** Error generating thumbnail: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The given URL was not found on this server" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The given URL was not found on this server, NSUnderlyingError=0x170255990 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

I tried to initialize the filepath like this: URL(string: filepath), but no luck either.

It works just after filming the video. Until you reopen the app and then it fails again...

Comment: Where is the path? Is it in the Documents folder? Never store and reuse and absolute path. Your app's sandbox can change.

Comment: This is the url that it generates (already removed the absolute path): 
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4280210D-6479-4036-AF5C-E9005070F57C/tmp/51473631576__912FB214-4D3A-4A0C-A5D4-D6F166D1DC06.MOV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think that the problem was that I was trying to access a temporary address (the private and tmp in the url should've tipped me off :s)

Ended up creating the video and moving it to the documents directory.